# nginx http to https redirect stopped working after upgrade to v1.10.3

Tags: linux, nginx, redirect, https

I recently upgraded nginx v1.8.1 to v1.10.3. When I did so, the "standard" redirect config for http to https stopped working (it directs to the nginx default page). I verified this by simply rolling back to the pre-install upgrade and it worked again. Can anyone provide me with an answer or suggestions as to why this stopped working? The code used for redirecting is below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen   443;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ...

}
```

Comment: Please give us your actual Nginx config, rather than an example, it could be a typo. For example you probably want "listen 443 ssl".

Comment: @Tim This is from my actual Nginx config, I just used "example.com" for privacy. I did try using "listen 443 ssl" but it didn't make any difference in anything.

Comment: You need to post the complete configuration in order for us to find out what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is to try adding

```
server_name example.com www.example.com;
```

to your port 80 server. It should be taken from the request according to [the Nginx reference](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host) (excerpt below), but it's worth a shot.

> $host in this order of precedence: host name from the request line, or
>   host name from the “Host” request header field, or the server name
>   matching a request

You could also try making the port 80 server default_server.

If this doesn't work please edit your question give more detail - a more full version of your config, curl -i showing your request (ie the curl command line) and the response headers, plus matching Nginx error and access logs for that curl.

This may not work, but it's part of the problem solving steps, and it's too long for a comment. If people could try to resist down voting me if it doesn't work that'd be great.